# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name "NoB2BSiteUpgrade"

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell, content-database

I tried to use the mount database with NoB2BSiteUpgrade like below

Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication https://sitename -NoB2BSiteUpgrade

But I am getting the below error

> a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
> 'NoB2BSiteUpgrade'

Not sure what I am missing here. I am trying this in a SharePoint 2010 server

Comment: What is your SP2010's patch level?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on two different SharePoint Server 2010 farms, one with May 2020 patch installed. The cmdlet works just fine in SharePoint 2013 though. I would suggest you install the latest patch and test again.